# Two different text align in a span

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Within a bootstrap `<span>` element, I'm trying to align the word "amount" to the left, and the "$" to the right, but having them on the same label. I tried to have a `<span>` inside another `<span>` and apply different CSS to them, like the code below, but that didn't work. How should I deal with this? Can someone please help? Many thanks!

HTML:

```
span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">amount <span id="dollarsign">$</span></span>
```

CSS:

```
.input-group-addon {
    min-width:300px;  
    text-align:centre;
    font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
 }

 #dollarsign{
    text-align:right;   
 }
```

Comment: What part didn't work? The amount is to the left and the $ is to the right!

Comment: How come that $ is still to the right after "amount " at my end..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can float the dollar sign right.

```css
.input-group-addon {
  min-width: 300px;
  font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
  text-align: left!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">amount <span class="pull-right">$</span></span>
```

Comment: You can just use the bootstrap-supplied `.pull-right` class instead of adding an id just to give it `float:right`

Answer (score 3):

`.input-group-addon` is set to `width: 1%;` in Bootstrap v3.) For very good reason. Don't mess with it. The proper way to go is:

- set a min-width on that thing `min-width: 10rem` (`%`,`em`, `rem`, `px`...)
- use a `<span>` insde and float it.

```html
<div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"  style="min-width: 12rem; text-align:right;"><span style="float: left;">I am floating-left</span>$</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
      <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
    </div>
```

The key here is `min-width`. See example. Also, if needed, disable the `min-width` on very narrow device and wrap some of that text in a class that hides it on mobile (have a short version of it).

```css
.input-group-addon:first-child {
  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
}
.input-group-addon .floater {
  float: left;
}

.input-group {
margin-bottom: 15px;
}




body {
 margin: 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items:cener;
 justify-content: center;
 min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="floater">I am floating-left</span>$</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
      <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
    </div>
    
        <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="floater">Floating-left</span>$</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
      <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
    </div>
    
        <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="floater">$</span>Not floating left</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
      <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
    </div>
```

**Note:** Do not use more than 1 `<input>` in an `.input-group`!
**Also:** If you use it on only one item, you might want to set a right margin on the inner span and you're done. Just remember it will always shrink if you leave it room, because it has a set `width:1%`.

Comment: Sorry I might not have explained it quite well. What I want to achieve is that $ and word"amount" in the same label, but one to the left and one to the right. like this: "amount        $"

Comment: See the update. That's the principle. Use margins. Of course, you want to do it in stylesheet, and use a class, if you have more cases. You got this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use float and text-align:

HTML

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2"><span>amount </span>$</span>
```

CSS

```
#sizing-addon {text-align:right}
#sizing-addon2 span {float:left;}
```

You could also  use (inline-)flex and justify-content:space-between